# Moving Zend from LAMP to Shared Server error

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 
'DirectoryIterator::__construct(/modules) [<a href='directoryiterator.--construct'>directoryiterator.--construct</a>]: 
failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in 
/home/www/zf/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:289 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/www/zf/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(289): DirectoryIterator->__construct('/modules') 
#1 /home/www/zf/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php(72): Zend_Controller_Front->addModuleDirectory('/modules') 
#2 /home/www/zf/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(683): Zend_Application_Resource_Frontcontroller->init() 
#3 /home/www/zf/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(626): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('frontcontroller') 
#4 /home/www/zf/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL)
#5 /home/www/zf/library/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Boot in /home/www/zf/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php on line 292
```

That is the error I'm getting. I have checked all the paths and looks like its all correct. I have no clue what this error is all about. Please help.

This is my index.php

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/home/www/mf/application'));

//path for public
defined('PUBLIC_PATH')
    || define('PUBLIC_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/home/www/iops.axeleron.biz'));


// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/home/www/zf/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));




/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';


// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/home/www/mf/application/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Comment: there is something tricky in all the `/home/www/` you got there... what have you done with your directory structure? Is it really that comlicated?

Comment: I have got my public files under the subdomain iops.axeleron.biz
I got the zendframework in the folder "zf" and the zend project files from the LAMP in the directory "mf"

Answer (score 0):

Your `APPLICATION_PATH` looks wrong. If you're happy hardcoding it, you probably want:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', '/home/www/mf/application'));
```

Apply the same change to the `PUBLIC_PATH` line below as well.

Generally you don't want to hardcode paths though, and what you probably had before was:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

which should still work. This works out the application path using the path to the current file.

Comment: I'm getting this error when made the changes suggested by you?

Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/iops.axeleron.biz/index.php on line 28

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path=':.:/usr/local/php5.3/lib//php') in /home/www/iops.axeleron.biz/index.php on line 28

Comment: Ah yes, your include path part is incorrect as well. Change this line: `realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/home/www/zf/library'),` to: `realpath('/home/www/zf/library'),

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the response. I solved the problem myself. My server needs to have hardcoded path everywhere, so I made those changes in config and index.php and its working like a charm.

Thanks for all your help!...